# duplicates values in array using reduce explaining

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, duplicates

can anyone tell me about using reduce with spread

```js
var arr = [10,10, 8000, 8000, 2, 17]
var unique = arr.reduce((x, y) => x.includes(y) ?  x : [...x, y], []);

console.log(unique)
```

what the `x` do in that  scope ? and the `spread syntax` also  ? and the last  empty array `[ ]`

when i console.log the x , it is only show the first value array, and the x the rest values in arrays

Comment: All your questions are answered at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps using different variable names would help:

```
var arr = [10,10, 8000, 8000, 2, 17];
var initialiser = [];

var unique = arr.reduce((output, currentElement) => {

  // If our output array includes the current element
  if (output.includes(currentElement)) {

    // Return the output without adding to it
    return output;
  } else {

    // Otherwise create a new array by spreading out
    // the elements of the output array, and adding the
    // current element.
    // `return output.concat(currentElement);` would
    // give the same result
    return [...output, currentElement];
  }

// Pass in the initialiser object which
// we call `output` in each iteration
}, initialiser);
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to understand how the reduce function works. It expects 2 parameters: a function and an initial value for your accumulator.

```
(x, y) => x.includes(y) ?  x : [...x, y]
```

this is a function, that is called inside the reduce call. for x the accumulator is passed, for y the current value of the array. So this function takes accumulator and current value, checks whether the value is already in the accumulator (by using includes). If it is the function returns x, the accumulator, but if y is not in x, the function returns a new array for the accumulator with all elements of the old accumulator and the new value x.

This is by far not the best way to remove duplicates from an array, because every cycle you search through the whole array. If you need an array without duplicates consider using [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to reduce is a callback function.

It has two parameters accumulator(in this case x), and currentValue(in this case y)

Reduce will iterate over the array. On each run whatever is returned is the new value for accumulator, currentValue is whatever element is at the current iteration, so first iteration it would be 10.

The second parameter(There are others, but in this case) is a default value for 
the accumulators, in this case an empty array. if an array as a default value was not provided, we would have a problem, as the first element of the array is used as the initial accumulator value when no default value is provided, and we cannot append to a number.

To provide a little more clarity I'm going to expand the code a little more

```
var arr = [10,10, 8000, 8000, 2, 17]

var unique = arr.reduce((x, y) => {
  // does the array x include the value y
  if(x.includes(y){
    // We want an array with no duplicates, so we don't append y to the array, by
    // simply returning x
    return x;
  }

  // if we made it hear it must mean y is unique value so we want to add it to the   
  // array, so we want to return x with y include. We don't want to mutate x, so
  // return a new array with all the elements of x and y at the end
  // we do this using the spread operator(...) it will copy all elements of x into  
  // the new array
  return [...x, y]
}, []);


console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score -1):

like this：

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, value) {
  let result;

  // initial index
  let initialIndex = 0;

  // initial value
  let initialValue = this[0];

  // If there is a second parameter
  if (typeof value !== undefined) {
    initialIndex = 1;
    initialValue = value;
  }

  // Assignment initial value
  result = initialValue;

  // Traversing
  for (var i = initialIndex; i < this.length; i++) {
    // your callback and x,y here
    result = callback(result, this[i]);
  }

  // Return a new value
  return result;
};
```